# Output shape error of a convolutional neural network in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been working on a simple convolutional neural network model but the output doesn't seem to match the shape that I desire.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Reshape, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import *
from keras.layers.pooling import *
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.optimizers import rmsprop
from keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

model_CL = Sequential([
    Dense(64, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (200, 4, 1)),
    Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2, padding = 'valid'),
    Dropout(rate=0.3),
    Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')
])




model_CL.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'], optimizer = 'Adam')
model_CL.summary()


from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

es_CL = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=5)
mc_CL = ModelCheckpoint('best_model_CL.h5', monitor='val_acc', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

epochs = 50
hist_CL = model_CL.fit(CL_train_input, CL_train_label, validation_data=(CL_validation_input, CL_validation_label), batch_size=32, epochs=epochs, verbose=0, callbacks=[es_CL, mc_CL])
```

So my input size doesn't seem to be the problem.
My training set input shape is (13630, 200, 4, 1) where 13630 is the number of data, while my training_label is as follows. (13630, 2) 
What I expected the model output shape to be is (2,), but instead it seems like it's expecting (1,) as an output size.

So my error comes out like this.

Error when checking target: expected dense_28 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

just for the reference,

Model: "sequential_14"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

dense_27 (Dense)             (None, 200, 4, 64)        128

---

conv2d_27 (Conv2D)           (None, 200, 4, 64)        36928

---

max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPooling (None, 100, 2, 64)        0

---

dropout_14 (Dropout)         (None, 100, 2, 64)        0

---

conv2d_28 (Conv2D)           (None, 100, 2, 64)        102464

---

flatten_13 (Flatten)         (None, 12800)             0

---

## dense_28 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 25602

Total params: 165,122
Trainable params: 165,122
Non-trainable params: 0

here's the summary for my model. I'm not too sure why it's expecting (1, ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are taking out 2 as output, while you are giving in only 1 in the input layer.
Here is what you can do,

- In the output layer this one `Dense(2, activation = 'softmax')` you can change the first argument to 1, meaning that you are taking one output for a binary problem. Like this `Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')`.
- Another thing that you can do is, you can select a different loss function such as binary_crossentorpy and then you can convert your labels using `to_categorical()` which is a keras utils function. 
  `CL_train_labels = to_categorical(CL_train_labels)`
  I hope this can do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've acutally tried the first suggestion but it resulted in the same type of error for some reason. Plus, my train_labels have been converted using to_categorical() prior to these codes in fact. But I'll definitely give a look on using a different loss function.

Comment: My problem was that I chose the wrong loss function for my case which you have mentioned. Setting binary_crossentropy as my loss function solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `training_label` is one-hot encoded. So you want to use `categorical_crossentropy` instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` which expects shape `(None, 1)`